# How to fix double tap hover issue on iOS in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, wordpress-theming, double-click

I am working on a website: mariekevancamp.com which is using the wordpress theme espied. The main page consists of multiple square tiles. To open a project you need to click on the tile. This works on android devices. However on iOS you need to double tap to open the project, which is not what I want. Apparently this is not a bug but a kind of implementation that is supposed to happen on iOS when you have a hover effect on a link with visibility or display. Is there any way to fix this with just the wordpress CSS editor? I like the hover effect, but I would like to immediately go to the project’s page after one click. If this is not possible in iOS, is there a way to remove the hover effect by adding some code in the CSS editor (additional CSS)?

Comment: Please show us the relevant code - put it direct into your question. In particular you hint at a hover as well as a click state being required so the CSS and related HTML are important.

Comment: There is a way you can make the hover effect a default on iOS devices for your website. Would you like to go with that implementation? If so, then I'll share the code.

Comment: Since I have used a wordpress theme, I can only add additional lines in the CSS editor which override the original CSS. I cannot easily edit the HTML and CSS code. That is why I added a link to the website and not the relevant code.

Comment: @VinayJain yes please, that would be great. Hope I can implement this easily in Wordpress

Comment: @VinayJain what was your original answer? I transferred everything to a self-hosted site. The supports rule doesn't work. I would like to try the media query again

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code in `functions.php`:

```
function fix_ios_double_tap_issue() {
  echo '<script>document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);</script>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'fix_ios_double_tap_issue');
```

Comment: This worked for me for audio play buttons on webpage, that needed to be tapped twice on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
   /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
    .js .page-template-page-templatesportfolio-page-php .jetpack-portfolio .image-link {display:block !important;}
    .js .page-template-page-templatesportfolio-page-php .jetpack-portfolio .view-link {opacity: 1 !important;}
    .js .page-template-page-templatesportfolio-page-php .jetpack-portfolio .post-thumbnail-wrapper {background-color: #007cad !important;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the code in the CSS editor, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure but it might be that the CSS editor is restricted to changes in styling and does not support these kind of CSS rules.

Comment: Can you try putting it in Appearance > Theme Editor > Your Child Theme > Style.css

Comment: I don't have that functionality. I think this is not available for premium members. Maybe the issue will be hard to solve given the constraints of the standard CSS editor. But it also doesn't make sense that you would need to pay €33/month to be able to edit the code of your wordpress site.

Comment: Probably you're using managed WordPress hosting. You can try installing a file manager plugin and get your work done.

Comment: Ok I will first look into this before I continue with the code!